# How to list all files present in a mercurial repository at a given changeset?

Tags: python, mercurial, commit, release

I am working on a python script to generate release notes.
I am looking for a way to list all files present in a given changeset.
I am not interested in what changed, but the whole list of files.

For the moment i thought about two possibilities:

1. update the repository to a given changeset and get the list of files
2. customize with the hg log via template

(1) above is not so elegant, and I have not been able to implement (2).

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: `hg status --change REV

`

Answer (score 0):

I thinks i found the answer by myself:

```
hg manifest -r <changeset>
```

Comment: In general, I'd recommend `hg files -r <rev>` instead, as it is more general (can write zero-terminated strings for use with xargs, can handle file patterns, and deals with subrepos). `hg manifest` is mostly a specific case of `hg files`.